# Rails test for contents in a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Comment form that also contains an Attachment form.

Comment model contains:

```
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachments
```

Comment form contains:

```
<%= f.fields_for :attachments do |builder| %>
  <%= builder.input :name, :label => 'Attachment Name' %>
  <%= builder.file_field :attach %>
<% end %>
```

Comment Controller contains:

```
def new
  @comment = Comment.new
  @comment.attachments.build
```

If the user adds an Attachement, everything works fine.

I would like the user to be able to submit a Comment with or without an Attachment.

Right now, if the user enters a Comment without an attachment, the form re-displays and the Comment does not get created.

This is the log if I try to post a new Comment without an Attachement:

```
Started POST "/comments" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-19 10:34:31 -0700
Processing by CommentsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",   "authenticity_token"=>"A6MOeMgoGUDmGiJr9PWinHVTAa7X63fgtA7+2my0A2Y=",  "comment"=>{"user_id"=>"1", "status_date"=>"2013-12-19",  "worequest_id"=>"10", "statuscode_id"=>"", "comments"=>"test",  "attachments_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>""}}}, "_wysihtml5_mode"=>"1",  "commit"=>"Save Comment"}
Tenant Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "tenants".* FROM "tenants" WHERE  "tenants"."subdomain" = 'ame' LIMIT 1
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE  "users"."tenant_id" = 1 AND "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
(0.1ms)  BEGIN
(0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
```

I need to figure out the right code so that the Attachment fields show up in the form, but the Comment will get created if no Attachment is selected.

Maybe I need to put code in the Attachment controller?

Comment: So what's your question? Are the results of what you tried not what you expected? If so, what were your results and what did you expect?

Comment: `@comment.attachments` can not be `nil`, it always returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object which contains 0 or more records from the DB translated in ruby objects. To test if the attachment is present, use `.present?` (test if the array contains at least one element) : `@comment.attachments.present?` --- A little tip for you @Reddirt : never use tests like `.nil?` or `== nil?` or `!= nil?`, always use `.present?` (or its opposite, `.blank?`)

Comment: Thanks @MrYoshiji - but, I was not thinking correctly.  Doing the test in the New section only changes whether the Attachment fields display on the form.  I need to figure out another way.

Comment: Can you re-type your question to eliminate the useless code/text and add the relevant pieces of code/text? Please be clear in what you want exactly. (ex: on create action, if the user did not send any attachment, i do not want to create the comment object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the Comment model to this:

```
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachments, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:attach].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Rails [present?](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/present?) method to check if the object is not blank:

```
@comment.attachments.build if @comment.attachments.present?
```